# ASP.Net VB - Displaying Data Accordion Style

Tags: javascript, vb.net, gridview, datatable, treeview

I'm looking to display a list of comments, username, and date/time the comment was made.  I am getting my results from a query in a datatable.  I have the datatable displaying.  I would like to display my results is an "Accordian" style treeview.  Is there a way to make a treeview display more than just one datafield on a line?  Is it possible to have it display a table?  Would it be easier to use javascript / J Query to modify the table?

If you have any other ideas / suggestions, that would be really helpful!  Just looking for guidance / ideas.

Cheers,
Greg

Comment: you can take a look at something ready to use http://www.p51labs.com/accordion/ I hope it will give you some better ideas... You can find plenty of examples to modify table using jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use an `asp:listview` to display your information, because with a listview, you get full control of what html is rendered (more info on the listview control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337898.aspx).

Then, for the "Accordian" style, you could use JQuery `.show` and `.hide`. Then you decide if you have only one "line" showed at the same time by closing every "line" when you show one, or not.